# opencv or imagemagick for highlighting differences

Tags: image, opencv, imagemagick

I am working on a project in which I need to highlight the difference between pair of scanned images of text.

Example images are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86fzQ.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNvq7.jpg).

I am building a webapp based on HTML,JS for this.
I found that openCV does support highlighting differences between 2 images.
Also I saw that imageMagick also has such support.
Does openCV has support for doing automatic registration of images?
And is there a JS module for openCV?
Which one is more suited for my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Simplistic way:

Suppose the images are perfectly aligned and similarly illuminated: subtract one image from another pixel by pixel, then threshold the result, filter out noisy blobs, and select the biggest ones. Good for a school project

**2.** A bit more complicated: 
Align the images, then find a way to uniform the illumination, then apply the simplistic way.
How to align:

- Find the text area in two images, as being a darker than the file color.
- Find its corners
- Use getPerspectiveTransform() to find the transform between images.
- warpPerspective() one image to another.

Another way to register the two images is by feature matching. It has quite an extensive support in OpenCV. And findHomography() will estimate the pose between two images from a bigger set of matching points.

**3.** Canonical answer:
Align the image.
Convert it to text with an OCR engine.
Compare the text in the two images.

Comment: ,actually i had got some initial success on using ImageMagick but now I am working on some more complex text-images like the one here. http://imgur.com/YJekv,Xpebk#0 Can you suggest if openCV's feature-matching can be used for these kind of images as the size of letters are also different in these images

Answer (score 1):

Well, besides the great help given by vasile, you also need the web app answer.
In order to make it work in a server, you will probably need a file upload form, as well as an answer from the server with the applied algorithm. There are several ways you can do it depending on the server restrictions you have. If you can run command line arguments, you would probably need to implement the highlight algorithm in opencv and pass the two input files a an output one for the program. A php script should be used for uploading the files, calling the command line program, and outputting the result to the user.
Another approach could be using java and JavaCV in a web container like Apache Tomcat, for instance.

Best regards,
Daniel